Maven Multistage Build Endless Loop when build image
I want to containerize a java app.
I have this dockerfile:
FROM maven:3-eclipse-temurin-17 AS maven
RUN mkdir -p /opt/app/src
COPY src /opt/app/src
COPY pom.xml /opt/app
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.m2 mvn -f /opt/app/pom.xml -DskipTests=true clean package

FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jre-focal as builder
WORKDIR application
COPY --from=maven /opt/app/target/microprofile_db_access.jar application.jar
RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar application.jar extract

FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jre-focal
WORKDIR application
COPY --from=builder application/dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=builder application/spring-boot-loader/ ./
COPY --from=builder application/snapshot-dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=builder application/application/ ./
CMD ["java","-jar", "application.jar"]

I build the image:
docker build -t backend:1.0 .

Output in console:
     => [builder 4/4] RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar application.jar extract                                     149.9s
     => => # [AUDIT   ] CWWKF0012I: The server installed the following features: [appSecurity-3.0, cdi-2.0, distributedMap-
     => => # 1.0, el-3.0, jaxrs-2.1, jaxrsClient-2.1, jdbc-4.2, jndi-1.0, jpa-2.2, jpaContainer-2.2, json-1.0, jsonb-1.0, j
     => => # sonp-1.1, jwt-1.0, microProfile-4.0, monitor-1.0, mpConfig-2.0, mpFaultTolerance-3.0, mpHealth-3.0, mpJwt-1.2,
     => => #  mpMetrics-3.0, mpOpenAPI-2.0, mpOpenTracing-2.0, mpRestClient-2.0, opentracing-2.0, servlet-4.0, ssl-1.0].   
     => => # [AUDIT   ] CWWKF0011I: The microprofile_db_access server is ready to run a smarter planet. The microprofile_db
     => => # _access server started in 40.759 seconds. 
    

The first stages are working in the build, but in the last stage the server gets started and remains started, so the build process is still in process as long as i am running the server. Do i understand the concept of the multistage build in the correcty way? I thought i need first to build the image and then i can run it.
